# Предлоги до / по: подразумевание "включительно" ещё не считается нормой?

Tags: семантика, предлоги, даты

Уточняющий вопрос: для предлогов до / по подразумевание "включительно" ещё не считается нормой?

Пример:

> Приём документов до 5-го мая.

Т.е. последний день приёма документов — это 4-е мая?